# Latest "A Term of Commutative Algebra" by Altman and Kleiman?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, soft-question, books

Where can I find the latest revision of *A term of Commutative Algebra* by Allen B. ALTMAN and Steven L. KLEIMAN? Is my 2013 version ok?

It is hard to locate the latest one; many old revisions and pointers to them are randomly scattered across the web. (Details: The first page of a web search showed me all 4 versions below. Furthermore, none of the seemingly official sites shows the revision date, only saying "2013 issue". You can't check the version until you actually donwnload one and open it.)

This free textbook is intended to be an update of, and an improvement to "A & M", i.e. *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyah and MacDonald.

Comment: What does it mean to ask whether your version is OK?  Also, if you know the answer, then why are you asking?

Comment: @LSpice Surely, [asking and answering your own questions is OK](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.182172452.269597383.1614591584-12065688.1564395774)? In fact, it's "explicitly encouraged" to do so.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda There's a feeling among some users (disclosure: me included) that this SO rule is not so appropriate for MO; we developed our own norms on MO before we formally became part of the StackExchange network. I say this regardless of the merits or otherwise of this particular question

Comment: I agree with both @YemonChoi and Carl-Fredrik. This question is equally or maybe more appropriate for Math SE than MathOverflow. I don't know if it is possible to migrate it. Designating authorship of the question (and answer) as Community Wikis seems reasonable, as an ad hoc measure.

Comment: It seems [several](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1338/answer-your-own-question-share-your-knowledge-qa-style-is-there-consensus) such [discussion threads](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/480/should-questions-to-which-i-already-know-the-answer-in-advance-be-appropriate-fo) seem to have been warranted already! There the consensus seems to be as @YemonChoi phrases it; I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the latest from these sites:

- [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325591008_A_term_of_Commutative_Algebra)
- [Worldwide Center of Mathematics](https://the-center-of-math-store.constantcontactsites.com/textbooks/post/p_2398391)
- (Obsolete) [DSpace @ MIT](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/116075)  - As of 2022, this version is not the latest, but of the year 2018.

Notice they are surely the latest, although all these three sites only show the *initial* release year, 2013. Download is open to everyone, including ResearchGate.

Make sure you have **at least the 2017 version** or later, which was a great expansion. Compare these:

- [Ver 2021-04-11](https://web.archive.org/web/20210703201703/https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Steven-Kleiman/publication/351211952_A_Term_of_Commutative_Algebra/links/608b6380458515d315e6bc21/A-Term-of-Commutative-Algebra.pdf): 441 pages, 612 exercises.
- [Ver 2018-03-11](https://web.archive.org/web/20210223003406/https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Steven-Kleiman/publication/325591008_A_term_of_Commutative_Algebra/links/5b2189a2aca272277fa96217/A-term-of-Commutative-Algebra.pdf): 426 pages, 594 exercises.
- [Ver 2017-08-06](https://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/en/math/groups/arithmetic_geometry/teaching/exercises/Altman_-Kleiman---A-term-of-commutative-algebra-_2017_.pdf): 423 pages, 585 exercises.
- [Ver 2013-09-01](http://web.mit.edu/18.705/www/13Ed.pdf): 258 pages, 324 exercises.
- [Ver 2012-09-03](http://web.mit.edu/18.705/www/12Nts.pdf): 208 pages, $\gg 200$ exercises.

(Let us define the *page number* by the last page number *printed in* Arabic numerals. ResearchGate adds an extra front cover, so the pdf page number is not necessarily well-defined.)

Acknowledgement: Emeritus Professor Steven Kleiman kindly answered the OP's question concerning this point.